# Website loading speed - slow html loading

Tags: html, performance, apache, magento, apc

Who can help me.

I have a webshop running on magento 1.6.2.0.
A VPS server with apache 2.
I have APC and memcache, varnish cache and fooman speedster running.

The main page has acceptabel loading times ...
But when i go to a category page it takes a lot longer ...

But the must waiting time is consumened by waiting on the html page to load ...
See the screenshot:
[image]

The loading time is now around 2-5 seconds, but when its busy on the site it can run up to 10-15 seconds ... so much to slow ...

When i take alook with firebug i see the most time of the loadingtime is waiting ...

So my question is, how can i reduce this?

Comment: Find out what the bottleneck is. Perhaps something on the server (db access) is taking long.

Comment: its seems that there are lot of individual resourses loading. the request-response round trip is always is expensive. if its possible, try to import all the .js in one single file at server side itself and then load this just one new big file. this will greatly reduce round trip cost. Also for images u can load them as sprites.

Comment: the images will load after the page is shown. (i think the deflate command does this).
The most time is waisted by waiting on the first line, the html page, to load ...
I think this is the bottleneck.
(i optimized db yesterday, this is helping a bit)
Any more solutions?

Comment: Based on the net panel output, Fooman Speedster is not working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

benmarks and josh pennington are on the right lines, ingnore the others who are telling you to cut down the number of requests for now as the extra requests are a distraction right now.

The problem is the HTML page takes too long to generate, and under load this gets worse.

Often this is down to the DB being under too much load, either through poorly optimised queries or not having enough memory.

You need to establish what queries are executed on that page, and what their performance profile is e.g. memory, IO, CPU usage.

What size VPS do you have? You also have to consider whether it's got enough memory.

Also are you running Apache? If so how many workers does it have. What may be happening is that at busy times there manpy not be enough workers and they may not be able to process quickly enough so at busy times some requests are queuing whil waiting for a worker to become available.

Comment: Give Magento 256 to 512 for its memory_limit and look into increasing innodb memory pool sizes. Magento will be happiest on a 2-4 core processor with 2MB memory. One useful tool for making adjustments to MySQL settings is the [MySQL Tuner Tool](https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl) which analyzes your MySQL stats and makes recommendations for better performance. Adding a full page cache also helps immensely. We were hitting 650+ users last week with no appreciable slowdown on the front end. It's all hardware resources and caching. Magento will run as fast as the resources you allow.

Comment: Hi, its a AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6128 server (1 core) with 2 GB ram (1gb garanteed).
Do you think this is enough?
Further more i am running apache2. I don't know how much workers (where do i find this?)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely data related. Create and browse to a category with no products and note the response time; this will indicate if its a category data issue. You can use the profiler to narrow down the culprit. In Admin > System > Configuration > Advanced: Developer, *set the Developer Restriction IP to your IP* and enable the profiler. Then in index.php uncomment Varien_Profiler::enable();

You should then see output after your normal response body. You can trace through that output and find the poor-performing area somewhere in the middle.

Comment: That is actually the best answer I've seen to troubleshoot Magento's performance issues. Tks heaps benmarks.

Comment: Download [AOE Profiler](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-profiler.html) and you'll be really happy.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is look at the Magento whitepaper. It has a lot of good tips for how to finetune PHP, Apache and MySQL for top performance.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/whitepaper

I will say that separating the MySQL server from the Apache one can make a world of difference. Magento makes very heavy use of Innodb which can be seen as very slow if the DB server is not optimized to use as much memory as it is allowed to.

Comment: Also go to webpagetest.org and do a speed test there. I would look at enabling mod_expires on Apache so you only have to download all those js files once. They will have a lot more suggestions for you. I would do this first before you modify the code. In my experience, you should get your server services running at peak performance before you modify your code too much. That way you know you server is firing on all cylinders before you try to make the code faster.

Answer (score 1):

One really great improvement you can make is replace Apache with Nginx. I've seen great speed and stability improvements using Nginx. Some things MYSQL tuner will tell you is to optimize your tables, increase your innodb_memory_pool_size, and increase max_heap_table_size      and tmp_table_size. If you can afford it, bump up your server to 4GB and give more memory to MySQL and PHP. Gzip also has an effect on time to first byte and might slow you down a bit with only one processor. You could investigate Cloudflare as an alternative/addition for caching. One last thing is that catalog pages tend to have lots of images. Make sure those are optimized (I use ImageOptim) and change gif to png if possible. There is so much more to go over, but start with this.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to implement a javascript code to load all the images (high resolution) after the page loads. Just try to get images after the page loads threw a ajax call

```
function init() {
...function to call all the images threw ajax
}
window.onload = init;
```

well I tried out given below code to come up with the least time to load images.
I put all images with a common div name and set their visibility to hidden...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#img").css('visibility','visible') //img is div for all the images on the webpage 
});
```

but ajax call give me a look and feel to get the images.

Comment: His problem is server side, not on the number of requests.

Answer (score 0):

You have pretty complex layered navigation setup which is going to be heavy on the server.

From experience moving to a specialist Magento web host can make the world of difference...it did to me.  I'm not sure if we are supposed to mention companies so I won't mention mine unless someone says it's ok to do it but a google search for Magento benchmarks should get you started.

Having a Three server approach makes a huge difference.

Comment: hi matthew, we need the complex layerd navigation for our customers ...
now i have a VPS server with 1 core and 2gb ram (1 gb garanteed).
But currently i am looking around for a faster server. What can you recommend? The next steps at my current ISP is 2 core with 4gb ram (2gb garanteed), or 3 core with 6gb ram (3 gb garanteed). Or else a dedicated server ...
What you mean by a tree server approach?

Comment: Hi Ronny

I use dx3webs.com, having the fastest hardware is not always the correct answer.  It is best if the MySql/Apache/PHP are all on different boxes optimised for that purpose.  I know in the magento setup that nginx is supposed to provide a better environment for one of them but I can't remember which one.  Anyway dx3webs are mage specialists and so can advise you better than I can.  There are other specialist mage hosts out there also so you may want to shop around